# read a csv file containing data separated by a delimiter in Python Flask

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to read a csv file, using the separator ',' but when I do line [1] I have an indexing error: I go out of range. For what reason?
what follows is a part of the code that manages the split but does not work.

```
with open(fileLocation, newline='') as fileCsv:
    reader = csv.reader(fileCsv, delimiter=',')
    first = True
    second = False
    prev = fileCsv.readline()
    reader= list(reader)
    for line in reader:
        if first:
            first = False
            second = True
            continue
        
        email = line[20].lower()
        nameSurname = line[0]
        msg=''
        if nameSurname == "" and email == "":
            return render_template('LoadCSV.html', login=loginStr(), avviso='err'+msg, fileLocation=fileLocation, category=app.category)
        data = line[3][0:10].replace("/","-")
        group = line[1]
        startingTime = line[16][11:]
        EndingTime = line[3][11:]
        language = line[10]
```

This instead is an example of the data contained in the file:

> Name Surname,Student,"Assessment timed out","2019/10/31
> 12:10:08",19,72,26,Fail,000000000,000000000000000,"English
> B1",Stefano,"2019/10/29
> 08:45:15",IDNUMBER,10.30.6.5,157.27.1.13,"2019/10/31
> 11:24:56",2706,,,xxxx.xxxx@gmail.com,,,,,,,,,"English B1"

> Name2 Surname2,Student,"Assessment timed out","2019/10/31
> 12:10:08",19,72,26,Fail,000000000,000000000000000,"Enghlish
> B1",Stefano,"2019/10/29
> 08:45:15",IDNUMBER,10.30.6.5,157.27.1.13,"2019/10/31
> 11:24:56",2706,,,xxxx.xxxx@gmail.com,,,,,,,,,"English B1"

Comment: Well, I copied your code and I have no error. Does your data contains of just two lines? Also I commented line with flask reference and it works.

Comment: @Kirill the problem is that line [0] contains all the data string while I would like it to contain, in the case of line [0] the data "Name Surname"

Comment: How do you create this csv?